# How can I make this column an unique column

Tags: sql, sql-server, erd

I have many applications. Each applications can have many languages assigned.
For each language there can be many translations.

Each translation has a `Key` column which is the primary key.

When 2 applications create a translation with `Key = "AdminAreaTitle"` there will be a duplicate key exception. I know this will rarely happen. But getting an exception that another application has this key already sounds pretty bad user experience.

What I want is a translation key per application so the primary key of translation would be `Key` and I guess `ApplicationName`.

How would you extend the design to get that behavior?

**Removed wrong image!**

**UPDATE**

This is now a sql view on the tables/relations not entity framework view anymore.

WITH **surrogate keys**

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

WITH **natural keys**

I must say I prefer this ERD more because its simpler to design and think about. The surrogate key is more disturbing.

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

I created a new database with 3 tables and all natural keys see the screenshot, but I keep getting an error message from sql management studio:

[image]

Comment: For 1 to Many and Many to Many relationship you can create a third table which refers to primary keys of the both tables as foreign key in the third table.

Comment: This seems too much. Why not create a FK_ApplicationName in Translation Table refering to Application table. And this FK is then a composite PK (Key and ApplicationName fields) ?

Comment: You are mixing two things here: a graphic representation of relations ( n <-> m , 1 <-> n) and table descriptions with primary keys. You cannot do that. Use either one of the two representations, not a mix of both. If name were the PK for application and iso639 the PK for language, then that would be an 1:n relation. However, as you put n:m there, there is obviously something missing, i.e. a bridge table as shubham agiwal suggests to implement n:m.

Comment: Yes the bridge table is missing as this is an entity framework model, sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: I, too, like the second diagram better. However, there is no connection between ApplicationLanguage and Translation, which I consider a lack. And: ISO639 must be part of Translation's PK, for otherwise you could only have one language per app and key, which makes no sense, I think. (Isn't it the app + key + language you need to get a text? If it were just app and key then your program would need to know which key to use for English and which for Spanish etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ERD you show is broken, because you show tables with their primary keys plus their relations (1:n, n:m) and these do not match. The keys of application and language suggest 1:n, but your graphic is labeled n:m.

What you might have now is something like (PK bold):

- application (**app_name**)
- application_language (**app_name, iso_lang**)
- translation (**key, iso_lang**, text)

But you want each application to define their own texts, so add the app_name to your composite PK for the translations table.

- application (**app_name**)
- application_language (**app_name, iso_lang**)
- translation (**key, app_name, iso_lang**, text)

Comment: sorry, but ERD was model for the entity framework, so it did not show the junction table Application_Language.

Comment: Okay, I just wrote a comment telling you that your ERD is broken, because graphic and tables do not match. However, I just notice that I failed to see that the ISO column is part of a composite PK in Translation. So I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I updated my question with a new ERD. What you think?

Comment: I just thought wether it would not more correct to split the Translation table into a Resource 1 and N Localisation table. Ok that would be a strong normalization I guess...

Comment: As to the new ERD: Okay, so you are using technical IDs now. That's okay. It's not better or worse then natural keys, just a matter of choice. However, you are not using this design correctly. ID should identify a record in a table. So how can ID not be the primary key for Translation, but only be part of a composite key?

Comment: Moreover, with technical IDs you no longer see the natural keys. That ID is unique in a table is obvious, but what natural keys in a table would also be unique? You have lost this information in your graphic. Maybe you can add U for unique right to the column names (or for the rare case that there are two different unique columns in a table, use U1, U2 etc.) So: What (apart from ID) makes a record in Translation unique?

Comment: Then as to your design: There is no relation between ApplicationLanguage and Translation. Is this desired? Why would you want an entry MyApp/Italian in Translation, when only MyApp/English and MyApp/Spanish are allowed in ApplicationLanguage?

Comment: The only MAYBE downside is see with your natural approach is when the application name changes (what should happen seldomly but it could happen as I work in a big company and they just did something with an app) then the on update cascade must propagate to the tables Translation and ApplicationLanguage. But both are 1 to N should that should work. What I do not like is that my http clients use the app name /language for translation requests, when we change the app name on server side then the client breaks. Thus I would prefer a surrogate key in the design.

Comment: I see. This actaully means to add a natural key :-) Rather than a technical ID which is only used inside the database to get the tables linked, you'd invent a constant. This can be a number (1, 2, 3, ...) or a name ('ORDERAPP', 'INVOICEAPP', ...). The real name for 'ORDERAPP' may be 'Orders' and later change to 'Orders and fun stuff', but of course these real names should not be used to link apps and database. I hence expected application.name to be such an artificial constant name as 'ORDERAPP' already.

Comment: Ah... so you mean when the appname changes it does not change the API_appname which is a further field hm correct! Ok I will later update my ERD and post here for final review. Hard to make a decision whats wrong/right probably in the end its taste...

Comment: Yes it is. I prefer natural composite keys after having worked with both models for many years. Technical IDs are easy to implement and to deal with, especially as sometimes there are no real-life keys at hand. But once you deal with big databases with deep hierarchy, they can really be a nuisance. For you usually query the data with a natural key (e.g. supplier number + order number + item number), but that can be spread over many tables (supplier table + order table + item table) in an ID model; so queries are harder to write and even data integrity is harder to ensure sometimes.

Comment: I see a gap of understanding with the natural keys: You said: "application_language (app_name, iso_lang)
translation (key, app_name, iso_lang, text)" Yes I agree key/appname/iso must be primary key. But where is your language table? And how do you connect your translation to the "parent" table with foreign keys? Would you please extend your answer?

Comment: You only need a language table when you have data for the language to store, e.g. the language's name ('English (US)', 'English (UK)', ...), but then why would you need these names? In order to display them in an app? Then they would belong in the translation table, so as to be able to display 'Inglés (EE.UU.)' to a Spanish user etc. So think about whether there is any other data for you to store in a language table. As to the FK: `translation (app_name, iso_lang) refererences application_language (app_name, iso_lang)` of course.

Comment: The language table holds the isocode. The language name like spanish is retrieved in the c# code no need to save it. There are too many unsure things. Maybe a translator guy is assigned to a applicationlanguageId. Its a first prototype :-)

Comment: So a language table is not badly needed here. You *can* use one, even without any other columns, just to have one place to say which languages (i.e. which ISO codes) are allowed in the database. But you can just as well go without it.

Comment: Yes to get all unique languages you would do a distinct(iso_lang) of the applicationLanguage table, is that in your mind? Your way is to workaround a N to M relation ;-)

Comment: I just did a quick setup in my sql studio with your sql tables: application_language (app_name, iso_lang)
translation (key, app_name, iso_lang, text) key/app_name/iso_lang are my composite PK. When I try to create a composite foreign key with translation.app_name and translation.iso_lang to both fields in application_language table I get an error: The columns in Application_Language table do not match an existing primary key. Any idea?

Comment: To make it work my app_lang table also needs the key is that right? if yes that would be overhead.

Comment: As to unique languages: I am just saying that maybe you don't need such an information. With your app_lang table you limit languages per app. Isn't this enough? Do you also need to limit languages for the database? Do you want the database to check whether an insert into app_lang refers to one of the languages allowed? If so, create that language table.

Comment: All this is not about circumventing to build an n:m relation, it's about whether the table is needed. Let's take an example: items have prices. Usually you would just have the price in the items table. But if you wanted to only use certain prices, you might build a price table, so as to have a foreign key from your items table to the prices table, thus allowing only certain prices in your items table. No big change, you still have items with prices; you only implemented an additional feature in your db to only allow for certain prices. The same *can* be done for languages in your db.

Comment: As to keys: The PK for Application_Language is app_name + iso_lang. You want to have a foreign key in Translation on these two fields. How can your DBMS say that app_name + iso_lang is no PK for Application_Language? Certainly you made a mistake somewhere. And what do you mean with `To make it work my app_lang table also needs the key is that right`? Are you talking about the "key" column? That must of course not be in the app_lang table. The app_lang table only consists of app_name + iso_lang and these two columns also build the PK for the table.

Comment: I did an Update 3 with a screenshot where you see a fresh DB + 3 tables defined. I did Translation.appname/isocode (FK) to ApplicatonRegion.appname/isocode (PK) then I get the error message you see in the screenshot. I can not retrace/understand the error message.

Comment: As you work with the natural key `appname` this should be the PK for application and the ID should be removed. ApplicationRegion would then get a FK on `application.appname`. The error you are getting means you are trying to create a translation FK on `ressourcekey` + `appname` + `isocode`, but there is no column `ressourcekey`  in ApplicationRegion. The foreign key should only contain `appname` + `isocode`.

Comment: ah darn... the id is wrong I know just a typo just realized it, but that did not cause the error. BUT my foreign key contains only appname + isocode as you can clearly see in the screenshot.

Comment: I don't know that tool, but in the window "Foreign Key Relationships" I see "Foreign Key Columns" = **RessourceName**, appname, isocode.

Comment: Yes sql server management studio suggested these 3 fields. I removed the REsourceKey. But it did not work. Now comes the best part: I removed the PK settings from the ResourceKey. Tried again to set the FK`s on Translation.appname/isocode NOW it works. THEN I set the PK on ResourceKey again and inserted some test data in a 3 tables. Then it worked! Before I choose the natural key way - have the surrogate way working with EntityFramework - I need to test with EF code first approach wether the natural FK`s work or I get exceptions due to a NotSupported case... see you next days ;-)

Comment: I made this behavior an extra question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748451/sql-management-studio-let-me-not-create-multiple-foreign-keys-to-multiple-primar

Comment: Ok I keep sticking to the natual keys. It worked fine with EF code first. All my tests are green ;-) Yes now I see => "...Do you want the database to check whether an insert into app_lang refers to one of the languages allowed? If so, create that language table." At first I wanted this feature that an existing language is attached to another application. But actually I do not really need it. Its enough with the 1:N solution less headache ;-) Thanks a bunch for all the learnings! +1

Comment: Today I discovered that EntityFramework 6 latest can not configure via code first a On Update Cascade on a Primary Key :P

Comment: And another comment from a M$ employee (MSFT) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/226b82b3-7915-4dca-9968-672baad927af/entity-framework-code-first-cascade-on-update?forum=adodotnetentityframework That means to me I have to add identity columns to my 3 tables. Too bad now I have to do 2 inner joins to get my translations for a given app and isolang ;-)

Comment: I for my part agree with the final post there; primary keys should not be changed. So I too, don't see this as an issue that must be addressed. Choose your PKs such that they don't change.

Comment: Yeah a bit long that I did sql but I agree too the PK value should just be in another field which can be changed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. There shall be a PK (consisting of one or more columns) and it must be fixed and never change. So what other field are you talking about?

Comment: PK field never changes which is natural key so like "application name". But as it must not change we need a duplicate field with similar name which can change?!

Comment: Well, you *could* start with using the same name in the PK (e.g. app_key = 'My Order App', app_name = 'My Order App'), but usually you would just invent a unique name (usually all upper or lower case) or number for each app, e.g. 'ORDERAPP' or 'ORD0001' or whatever. An app name can have special characters and spaces, which you usually don't want to see in an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

In the E-R model, your database is described with two tables (Application) and (Language), and a relationship (Translate) between them (entities are "nouns", and relationships are "verbs").

In a real DBMS, a relationship is a table that contains both the two primary keys of a certain application that is being translated in a certain language (and other characteristics proper of the traslation itself), making the relationship unique (an application may be translated in many languages, and a language can translate many applications, but an application may be translated only once in french).

```
APPLICATION
AppName (PK)
...

LANGUAGE
LangName (PK)
...

TRANSLATE
AppName   (PK)
LangName  (PK)
...
```

Comment: This is too much theoretical stuff. Would you please see the solution pragrammatic so I have a use of it? Since when is a relationship a table? A table is an entity.

Comment: @Elisabeth - If a table is an Entity, and Entities can have Relationships, where do you propose storing those relationships?  I could have lived at numerous addresses, and numerous people could have lived at the same address.  The entities are People and Addresses, and then you need a third table such as "Habitation" which contains the PersonPK and the AddressPK *(and probably a start and end date)*.  This way I don't need to create a new Person or Address if someone moves, just a new Habitation record.  Relationships really ***are*** tables.

Comment: The Entity-Relationship model is a theoretical model, which needs to be implemented in real DMBS systems.
As I said, in actual DBMS, relationships are tables too. And you can store in them also the so called "attributes" of the relationship, like dates, for example.

Comment: ah I guess we have a misunderstanding here. Your third table "Habitation" is this the junction table for People and Address?

Comment: Yes. You can call it a junction table. It's a good synonym for relationship.

Comment: Ok then I agree what you said. My diagramm was done for Entity framework where N to M relations are 2 tables. Its not a real ERD...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the language in the translation table, you should store the identity of the relation between the application and the language. That way the translations will be unique to the language for that application instead of just for the language.

As the application name seems like information that might change (not in meaning but in how they are described), I suggest that you use a numeric key for it.

Something like:

```
Application
  ApplicationId          int, identity, pk
  ApplicationName        nvarchar(50)

ApplicationLanguage
  ApplicationLanguageId  int, identity, pk
  ApplicationId          int
  LanguageId             int

Language
  LanguageId             int, identity, pk
  LanguageName           nvarchar(50)

Translation
  ApplicationLanguageId  int, pk
  Key                    nvarchar(20), pk
  Text                   nvarchar(max)
```

Comment: The Translation.Key must only be unique to an Application not Application_Language together, because a resource key has finally many translations/localizations and just like in the .NET String resource editor. How would you change your structure? Actually you just have to remove the ApplicationLanguage.ApplicationLanguageId and the Translation.ApplicationLanguageId. Now connect the Application.ApplicationId (PK) with the Translation.ApplicationId,Translation.Key (Both are PK but ApplicationId is also FK) Correct?

Comment: @Elisabeth: You are mistaken. If the key were unique for an application, then there would be only one record for MyApp/AdminAreaTitle for instance. So the entry would be either English or Spanish or whatever. This is not what you want, I guess. You want the key unique per application and langauge, so you can have one entry for MyApp/AdminAreaTitle in English and one in Italian, but not two in English. Hence the model shown here is correct.

Comment: damn... you are right. I always have this pivot table (.net string editor in mind) where one key is for all localizations. But in my database I have this key for many localizations.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner so to say then Guffa`s design is correct AND what I want.

Comment: Yes it's likely what you want. Guffa is suggesting the same datamodel as I, only he uses technical IDs (except for the Translation table, where you could be strict and add a seperate ID and add a unique constraint on ApplicationLanguageId and Key; but not being that strict is just as fine), and I use natural keys instead.