# SQL Server Management Studio does NOT let me create multiple foreign keys to multiple primary keys

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

I have a table `ApplicationRegion` in a one-to-many relationship to `Translation`.

I want to set FK's from `Translation.appname/isocode` to `ApplicationRegion.appname/isocode`

But that did not work as you can see from the screenshot.

When the FK configure window opens 3 columns are shown on the left/right side

```
appname
isocode
resourcekey
```

Then I chose as parent table `ApplicationRegion` and removed the resource key column from the FK setting.

And clicked OK but then I got the error you see on the screenshot.

[image]

Finally I made it work with that workaround and I would like to know why I had to use this workaround?

1. Remove PK from Translation.ResourceKey column
2. Open FK configure window
3. Only 2 columns appear now as foreign keys
4. I click OK
5. Now I add the PK again to Translation.ResouceKey column
6. I added test data to all 3 tables and everything is fine.

WHY this workaround?

**UPDATE**

HAHA...

[image]

Comment: I think you're creating the FK backwards.  The one with 2 PK fields should be primary, the one with 3 PK fields should be foreign.  Where it says 'foreign key base table,' you want that to not be Translation like in your image.

Comment: a foreign key relationship has a direction, from the parent table to the child.  I think you're trying to create the FK from the child table to the parent.

Comment: Yes but I always was doing that way.  Go to the child table and create FK`s to the parent table. I have never seen someone going to the parent table and choose the child table. I just did that way in sql management studio and the user interface in the FK dialog makes no sense this way.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you may want to consider using a surrogate key (ident) if you think you are going to be referencing Translation in a bunch of other tables. Otherwise you will be carrying those three keys two all tables that reference it instead of a single int column. You can always create a unique constraint on the three existing columns to ensure data integrity.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Its rather unlikely but yes then I should set an identity column + 3 unique index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must have hit a weird glitch in SSMS. I was able to create your schema using SSMS 2014 without any errors. It did pre-fill the three composite primary key columns when adding the new FK. I was careful to make sure they were all blanked out before I started to add the two columns in the FK. Maybe SSMS thought one of the blank rows still had data in it.

Edit: Just had one more thought, SSMS is know for caching any changes that are made when editing a table. For example, if you go to modify two tables and have both edit windows open. Then you change the PK in one window and then try to reference it in the second window, it will error because it has cached what the schema was for the first table when the window was first opened.

Here is my generated DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AppRegion](
    [appname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [isocode] [char](5) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AppRegion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [appname] ASC,
    [isocode] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Translation](
    [ResourceKey] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [appname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [isocode] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [text] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Translation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ResourceKey] ASC,
    [appname] ASC,
    [isocode] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Translation]   ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Translation_AppRegion] FOREIGN KEY([appname], [isocode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AppRegion] ([appname], [isocode])
```

Comment: I just saw other bugs like creating foreign keys in the FK dialog but even after refresh they are not shown under the Keys Folder. Could you please export the 3 table scripts then in your SSMS and paste here? I would make sure we speak about the same and test wether your sql breaks my SSMS ;-)

Comment: Sorry I abbreviated one table. And I left the first one out because it is unrelated to the FK.

Comment: See my UPDATE. so much about caching. My SSMS is gone wild... Thanks for the script it worked fine.

Comment: Wow, that is pretty strange. Closing SSMS and re-opening may help. Installing service pack 1 may help as well but I am not sure.

Comment: yes the new start of SSMS fixed it. I could also install SP1 true. Well even MS stuff is not bug free ;-) My Windows 10 task bar has had some icon bugs last weeks...